# Login with Steam OpenId(oidc-client-js)

Tags: steam-web-api, oidc-client-js

I've done auth with google when client auth, receive token_id, send it to server and server retrieve client account info base of that token_id. It was pretty easy because it was [documented](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent). Now I try to do with Steam but literally I have 4 rows about OpenID in [***steam docs***](https://steamcommunity.com/dev). I start using an openID browser lib [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/) but steam docs doesn't help me. The openID lib require this fields:

- authority
- client_id
- redirect_uri
- response_type
- scope

Steam docs offer just the provider, key and domain name and I really don't know where to start.

> Just download an OpenID library for your language and platform of
> choice and use http://steamcommunity.com/openid as the provider. The
> returned Claimed ID will contain the user's 64-bit SteamID. The
> Claimed ID format is: http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/

I get CORS Header problem because I use localhost and not a secure connection and I think I need to configure additional fields in oidc-client-js:

- metadata
- signingKeys

Any help will be **appreciated**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

tl;dr: Steam is not an OpenID ***Connect*** provider

I got the exact same problem.

I tried running chrome with CORS disabled to see if it would work, I got an error from oidc-client:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0  
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)  
    at XMLHttpRequest.s.onload (oidc-client.min.js?3809:1)
```

Which is easily understandable because https://steamcommunity.com/openid/.well-known/openid-configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xrds:XRDS xmlns:xrds="xri://$xrds" xmlns="xri://$xrd*($v*2.0)">
<XRD>
    <Service priority="0">
        <Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server</Type>        
        <URI>https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login</URI>
    </Service>
</XRD>
</xrds:XRDS>
```

Which is obviously not JSON.

The URL in the Type balise redirects to http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html, which can be found in the obsolete section of the [OpenID specifications page](http://openid.net/developers/specs/).

Additionally, you can find in the [OpenID Connect Discovery specification page](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderMetadata) that

> OpenID Providers supporting Discovery MUST make a JSON document available at the path formed by concatenating the string /.well-known/openid-configuration to the Issuer.

Which corroborate that the .wellknown/openid-configuration file of Steam OpenID endpoint was not made for OpenID **Connect**.

So I think it's safe to say that Steam is stuck to OpenID 2.0 and is not an OpenID Connect provider.

Now I have to look for an OpenID 2.0 js client, or switch for Google Sign-In.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my Steam OpenID Connect Provider:
https://github.com/ImperialPlugins/steam-openid-connect-provider

It is also available as a docker image on DockerHub:
https://hub.docker.com/r/imperialplugins/steam-openid-connect-provider

This allows you to use OpenID Connect with Steam.